# Strikethrough for entire row in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering, strikethrough

I have a `JTable` that takes their value over a mysql data base. I made several customcolumn renderers in order the `JTable` to show the data formated as I need them. What I need now is to add some strikethrough over some rows depending if the value on the last cell (5) in each row has a specific string value, (test) for example. The strike through must be in each cell of the row except the last cell (that has the test value). Can it work with the other custom column renderers without anything to mix up?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it can work with whatever column renderers you have written. It basically depends on how you write it.

Comment: Searching on the internet I find only exmples for cell rendering or entire columns , nothing for rows. Any available example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- why Html, why not use [TextAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) directly
- with all due respect to HFOE, and his knowledges sharing (forums.sun.com)

[image]

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TablePrepareRenderer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public TablePrepareRenderer() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50), false},
            {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25), true},
            {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35), true},
            {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00), false}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private Border outside = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.red);
            private Border inside = new EmptyBorder(0, 1, 0, 1);
            private Border highlight = new CompoundBorder(outside, inside);

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;
                Map attributes = (new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12)).getAttributes();
                //attributes.put(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD);
                attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
                if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    comp.setForeground(Color.black);
                    comp.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.orange);
                    int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 0);
                    if (type.equals("Sell")) {
                        comp.setFont(new Font(attributes));
                        comp.setForeground(Color.red);
                    } else {
                        comp.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
                    }
                } else {
                    comp.setFont(table.getFont());
                }
                jc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(jc.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5)));
                return comp;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TablePrepareRenderer frame = new TablePrepareRenderer();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is partial example of what you want to do,

[How to strikethrough text of a selected row(having checkbox in first column) of JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277220/how-to-strikethrough-text-of-a-selected-rowhaving-checkbox-in-first-column-of)

Please have a look at code, it should solve your problem.