# JTable Clickable Column Sorting: Sorting sorts content of cells, but doesn't update cell formatting?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a sortable `JTable` set up to use a custom extension of the `AbstractTableModel`. However, some behavior of this table is what I expected, and I would love some advice on how to figure this out.

I have the JTable set up to be sortable using:

```
thisJTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

This allows me to sort the table by clicking on the column headers as expected.

However, I find that when I sort the table by clicking on the column headers, the formatting (background and foreground color) of my rows are not sorted as well.

I had set up those rows to be color-coded based on the values they contain. When I sort by column header the formatting at a given row NUMBER stays the same (although the content that was previously in that row moved).

The color of the row is set by overriding the default `prepareRenderer` call for the JTable:

```
thisTable = new JTable(thisModel){

    //Set up custom rendering - Sets background color of row to correct value
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        CustTableModel thisModel = (CustTableModel) getModel();
        c.setBackground(thisModel.getRowBackgroundColor(row));
        c.setForeground(thisModel.getRowForeColor(row));
        return c;
    }
};
```

Is there a better/different way to approach this?

Should I be using a different method to do my rendering, a method which would update the rendering of the JTable on a sort?

Or do I want to look into writing my own sorting method?

**Solution (Thanks mKorbel!)**

I thought I would post my solution, since I had to play with this a bit since I wasn't sure if the new index would be passed to the prepareRenderer as well.

```
 thisTable = new JTable(thisModel){

    //Set up custom rendering - Sets background color of row to correct value
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {

        int viewIdx = row;
        int modelIdx = convertRowIndexToModel(viewIdx);
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        CustTableModel thisModel = (CustTableModel) getModel();
        c.setBackground(thisModel.getRowBackgroundColor(modelIdx));
        c.setForeground(thisModel.getRowForeColor(modelIdx));
        return c;
    }
};
```

Comment: I also may need to ensure that content-based formmatting is applied to rows after content is updated, but I haven't tackled that yet. I already am overwriting custTableModel.setValueAt(Object, int, int) so was thinking I had lots of options there, but thought I should mention that as well.

Comment: your prepareRenderer do nothing and complitating with CustTableModel thisModel = (CustTableModel) getModel();, remove that, [Renderer is only about formating, change Color, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+prepareRenderer), not for create JComponent, don9t do that

Comment: @kKorbel I am not sure if I follow your comment. getRowForeColor and getRowBackgroundColor add conditional coloring for the row, based on the content of the row (hence passing rowIdx). I am using the super method to create the component and then simply setting the correct background and foreground color on that component. I need to get the TableModel and cast it to my CustTableModel because getRow[Fore|Background]Color is not a defined method for other table models.

Comment: iam curious about the detail of getRowBackgroundColor()); code inside ? @Panky

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you have to [convert row index from View to the Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281306/714968)

```
int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
```

Comment: darn, you beat me (still fighting my new keyboard:-) +1, of course

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tip, I had been looking at the Javadoc for JTable for a while but didn't stumble upon this somehow.

Comment: @Panky: "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates."—[Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting); sadly, I've had to look it up more than once. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can enable table sorting by clicking on header using this 
`table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`

for more information visit this site http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/6-techniques-for-sorting-jtable-you-should-know

Comment: I can't believe that this answer is not the accepted answer. So elegant and simple. Thanks