# Cannot sort table headers by ascending or descending

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting

By default the `View` displays a sorted table which is great but cannot `Sort` the table columns by clicking on the table headers in ascending or descending order. The header column arrows goes up and down on clicks but the data stays the same. I am using jQuery jTable and sorting is enabled by default.

Is is possible to do this by using a jQuery?

Here's my code for your inspection:

View:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable({

        title: 'Top Tracks Played Records',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Date ASC',

        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("TopPlayedInVenueList1")'

        },
        fields: {
            TrackID: {
                title: 'Track ID',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
                tooltip: 'Track Name',
                sorting: true //This column is not sortable!
            },
            Date: {
                title: 'Date',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'dd - mm - yy',
                tooltip: 'DD - MM - YY',
                list: true,
                sorting: true //This column is not sortable!
            },
            TrackName: {
                title: 'Track Name',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
                tooltip: 'Track Name',
                sorting: true //This column is not sortable!
            },
            ArtistName: {
                title: 'Artist Name',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
                tooltip: 'Track Name',
                sorting: true //This column is not sortable!
            },
            Times: {
                title: 'Times',
                tooltip: 'Artist Name',
                sorting: false //This column is not sortable!
            }
        }
    });

    // All
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var endDate = todayDate.getDate() + '/' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (todayDate.getFullYear() + 100);
    var d = new Date();
    var st = d.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 111365);
    var startDate = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    $('#allrecordsstart').val(startDate);
    $('#allrecordsend').val(endDate);
    $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
        StartDate: startDate,
        EndDate: endDate
    });

    $('#allrecords').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var startDate = $('#allrecordsstart').val();
        var endDate = $('#allrecordsend').val();

        $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').show(0).delay(0).fadeIn(1000).jtable('load', {
            StartDate: startDate,
            EndDate: endDate

        });
    });
```

Controller: Edit for @CHash_Mile.. thanks a lot :) here's the code: **EDIT: 15/04/2014**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult TopPlayedInVenueList1(string StartDate = "", string EndDate = "", int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate-1k.xls";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);
                con.Close();
                System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(data);

                List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();

                foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
                    {
                        TrackID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("TrackID")),
                        Date = p.Field<DateTime>("DateTimes"),
                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("TrackName"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("ArtistName"),
                        Times = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("Times"))
                    };

                    daa.Add(top);
                }

                var listOrder = daa.Where(i => i.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate) && i.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate)).ToList();

                if (jtStartIndex + 150 > listOrder.ToList().Count)
                {
                    int val = listOrder.ToList().Count - jtStartIndex;
                    jtPageSize = val;
                }

                var newlist = listOrder.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jtSorting)) { jtSorting = "Date ASC"; }

                SortDirection sortDirection = jtSorting.ToLower().Contains("desc") ? SortDirection.DESC : SortDirection.ASC;
                string sortExpression = sortDirection == SortDirection.DESC ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" desc", "") : jtSorting.ToLower().Contains(" asc") ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" desc", "") : jtSorting;

                if (sortDirection == SortDirection.ASC)
                {
                 newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                 newlist = newlist.OrderByDescending(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();
                }

                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = newlist, TotalRecordCount = listOrder.ToList().Count });
            }
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Debugged using `Step Over` line by line and seems to be this line of the code is the culprit:

```
newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();
```

Because after this line I get error message on the View in browser:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Images: Edit for @CHash_Mile.. thanks a lot man :) screenshots of the debug:

`sortExpression` ---------- [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkFAU.png)
[image]

`newList` ---------- [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmVXa.png)
[image]

I'm sorry for taking your time soo much and really appreciate in what you're doing for me!

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321038/jtable-clickable-column-sorting-sorting-sorts-content-of-cells-but-doesnt-upd]

Comment: thanks for the link but that is for Java's jTable and I have issue with C# jQuery's jTable.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
[Sorting using Jtable example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277576/AJAX-based-CRUD-tables-using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-jTa#Sorting)

I see you are not using variable jtSorting for sorting. this gives property with which sorting needs to be done. Try with below code after loading newlist.

```
        SortDirection sortDirection = jtSorting.ToLower().Contains("desc") ? SortDirection.DESC : SortDirection.ASC;
    string sortExpression = sortDirection == SortDirection.DESC ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" desc", "") : jtSorting.ToLower().Contains(" asc") ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" desc", "") : jtSorting;

    if (sortDirection == SortDirection.ASC)
            {
                newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression))).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                newlist = newlist.OrderByDescending(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression))).ToList();
            }
```

Add below method -

```
    public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return obj == null ? null : obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

Add below enum inside your class -

internal enum SortDirection
    {
        ASC,
        DESC
    }

Comment: thanks @CHash_Mile - I am getting data from a `local excel` file so will this work? Because I had a go at it like two weeks ago and it didn't work for me, unless I didn't did it properly.

Comment: I see you are not using variable for sorting. Add this line

Comment: @CHash_Milk - thanks :) what line do you want me to add?

Comment: thanks alot for this and I see what you mean.. thanks for making it clear as I am kinda new to C# @CHash_Mike - I have tried your code but it gives me the following error "Does not exist in the current context" for these two `sortDirection` and `ReflectionHelper`. I have updated my code above for your inspection. thanks again a million :)

Comment: Updated my answer to load sortDirection and sortExpression. Check the updated code... Don't forget to mark as answer if it helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for that @CHash_Mike.. everything complied now properly :) on the `View` I get the following error. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I will surely mark it as an answer and will +1 rep and everything I can do.. Also buy u a drink :) I have been stuck with this for over two weeks. I have updated my code above for your inspection and thanks again a million :)

Comment: Keep debugger and check on which object is it giving object reference not set.. just check whats the value populated in "jtSorting". I sense there might be an issue.

Comment: I am confused about this line `internal enum SortDirection { ASC, DESC }`, where in the class do you want me to include? thanks again and sorry for taking your time soo much. Appreciate all your help :)

Comment: I had to change `SortDirection.ASC` and `SortDirection.DESC` to `SortDirection.Ascending` and `SortDirection.Descending` and had to add `@using System.Web.Helpers;` for `SortDirection`.. is that right? Thanks again man hope we get this to work almost there..

Comment: you could add that above method GetPropertyValue.. Yes you can even use System.Web.Helpers.SortDirection, no issues with that.. Add null check before using jtSorting or add this                     if (string.isNullOrEmpty(jtSorting)) { jtSorting = "Date ASC"; }

Comment: thanks for that I added `internal enum SortDirection { ASC, DESC }` above the `GetPropertyValue class` and removed `using System.Web.Helpers` and re-added `SortDirection.ASC` and `SortDirection.DESC` just to keep your code clean. By using the `if (string.isNullOrEmpty(jtSorting)) { jtSorting = "Date ASC"; }` above jtSorting is gives me this error `string does not contain a definition for isNullorEmpty`. How can I tackle this? think we are almost there and sorry for taking too long as you can tell I'm new with all this.. and thanks again for everything :)

Comment: rename it to "IsNullOrEmpty"

Comment: Wow that resolved the error but on the View I still get the same error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and I have updated my code above in the post.. I am soooo sorry for taking this long maybe you can help me one last time? thanks again and really appreciate it :)

Comment: debug whats causing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Comment: I am getting that error on the `View` as in after it's complied. No errors on the Visual Studio, it's on the browser that I'm getting.. thanks again Chash_Mike :)

Comment: YEs but while debuggin it must give it for particular line.. you would have to cehck that line. "Object ref" errors are easy to solve..

Comment: I hear you man but I tested it several times and it's not giving me any particular line - how can i check that? Let me tell u this that you have been a massive help! just can't get my head around this thing.. seems soo impossible :(

Comment: Man I'm hope that I'm right - Did a `Debug` line by line using `Step Over` and found out to be this line is the culprit. `newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();` because passed this line I get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.. Hope  it's right :) I have updated my full code in the post above and thanks.. hope you help out last time please :)

Comment: check what's value of sortExpression and also check whether any of newlist item is null

Comment: Man how can I thank you? You just showed me how to debug very effectively in VS.. `sortExpression` value is an `empty string` and `newList` gives out the `data` and is not null. I have posted the screen shots in the above post for your inspection man.. how can we tackle the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error? and you're the best man!!!!!!

Comment: what is the value for "jtSorting" when you get this exeception?

Comment: thanks @Chah_Mike - this is all I am getting when I put a `break point` in, `debug` and do `quick watch` for `jTSorting` [Screen shot](http://s22.postimg.org/gcu4xofdd/sort_Expression1.png). Looks like to be an `Empty` string. But on the View I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Can't believe that you're still helping me on this.. really appreciate it man :)

Comment: before debug when I hover over `jtSorting` I get the value `(parameter) string jtSorting` and during debug when I hover over, I get `Times ASC` value for `jtStoring`. Here's the [Screen shot](http://s13.postimg.org/813cobgev/sort_Expression2.jpg).. and thanks a billion :)

Comment: add this before SortDirection declaration `if (string.isNullOrEmpty(jtSorting)) { jtSorting = "Date ASC"; }`

Comment: EDIT: thanks for getting back :) I did what you suggested but it still gives the same error out `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I have updated my full code above for your inspection in the post above.. are we missing out something? thanks again man you're the best!!!

Comment: EDIT: I disabled `\\ defaultSorting: 'Times ASC',` in the `View` and now the `jtSorting` value in `Controller` `debugger` shows `null.` So `jtSorting` is picking the `Value` from the `View` but actually not doing anything and giving out the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

Comment: there is typo in one line, corrected it to '                string sortExpression = sortDirection == SortDirection.DESC ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" desc", "") : jtSorting.ToLower().Contains(" asc") ? jtSorting.ToLower().Replace(" asc", "") : jtSorting;'

Comment: thanks @CHash_Mike - i rectified what you suggest but still getting the complex `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: sorry to keep bugging you man but do you think of anything else what do we be missing out?

Comment: You need to find out which line is causing Object reference issue.. That particular varaible whichever is null, needs to be initialized, thats the only solution

Comment: thanks for that and sorry to keep on bugging you.. appreciate all your help. Sorry, I find it hard to learn new languages and small things like this making it soo complex for me to get it to work. `sortExpression` and `jtSorting` variables are both `nulls` and this `newlist = newlist.OrderBy(item => GetPropertyValue(item, sortExpression)).ToList();` of the code is giving out the `Object` reference. crazy hard man - `sortExpression` is already initialize though is it?

Comment: Please mark the answer if your originally asked question was answered correctly.

Comment: Hi, it's still not working.. will you help out for one last time please? I deggued the code and `sortExpression` and `jtSorting` variables are both null.. could you help to initialize both with values please? I exactly don't know how to do that.. thanks and hope you help.

Comment: are the sortExpression and jtSorting variables always null or only in certain case?