# How to write a custom DefaultTableCellRenderer to colorize specific cells and "preserve" the color of the others, Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, background-color, tablecellrenderer

I'm using netbeans with its gui builder in order to create a desktop application.
To colorize special cells in my jTables I have implemented a custom DefaultTableCellRenderer based on example code. So far it works.

My problem is the else case of the overwritten function "getTableCellRendererComponent()". I don't want that a cell which is not in the specified range becomes "white" - I want that these cells appear in the color they already had (e. g. I don't want to change there color to "white" if they have been "red").

I would be happy if somebody could help me on that!!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Steffen

```
class ColoredTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{

    /** constructor */
    public ColoredTableCellRenderer(int rowToColorizeStart, int rowToColorizeStop, int columnToColorizeStart, int columnToColorizeStop, Color color)
    {
        mRowToColorizeStart = rowToColorizeStart;
        mRowToColorizeStop = rowToColorizeStop;
        mColumnToColorizeStart = columnToColorizeStart;
        mColumnToColorizeStop = columnToColorizeStop;
        mColor = color;
    }

    private int mRowToColorizeStart = 0;
    public void setRowToColorizeStart(int rowToColorizeStart) {
        mRowToColorizeStart = rowToColorizeStart;  
    }
    public int getRowToColorizeStart() {
        return mRowToColorizeStart;  
    }

    private int mRowToColorizeStop = 0;
    public void setRowToColorizeStop(int rowToColorizeStop) {
        mRowToColorizeStop = rowToColorizeStop;  
    }
    public int getRowToColorizeStop() {
        return mRowToColorizeStop;  
    }

        private int mColumnToColorizeStart = 0;
    public void setColumnToColorizeStart(int columnToColorizeStart) {
        mColumnToColorizeStart = columnToColorizeStart;  
    }
    public int getColumnToColorizeStart() {
        return mColumnToColorizeStart;  
    }

    private int mColumnToColorizeStop = 0;
    public void setColumnToColorizeStop(int columnToColorizeStop) {
        mColumnToColorizeStop = columnToColorizeStop;  
    }
    public int getColumnToColorizeStop() {
        return mColumnToColorizeStop;  
    }

    private Color mColor = Color.WHITE;
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        mColor = color;  
    }
    public Color getColor() {
        return mColor;  
    }


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);    

        if( (row >= getRowToColorizeStart()) && (row <= getRowToColorizeStop()) && (column >= getColumnToColorizeStart()) && (column <= getColumnToColorizeStop()) && (isSelected == false) ) {
            cellComponent.setBackground(getColor());    
        } else {
           cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        return cellComponent;

    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need else block ...right?

Comment: that was waht i thought too, but without the else block, the whole table gets colored...

Comment: @Reddy - it _is_ needed, details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617446/203657

Comment: i understand that the else case is necessary, but is there an way to preserve the "previous" color of that cells belonging to the else case?

Comment: JTable has two dimmension you override only row, maybe then see my (why reinvent the wheel) EDIT

Comment: why didn't you read the answer I referenced above?

Answer (score 4):

> How to write a custom DefaultTableCellRenderer to colorize specific cells “only”, Java

code line

[public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object
     value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:714968%20%5Bjtable%5D%20DefaultTableCellRenderer)

talking about whats happens

- if cell is selected or not (`boolean isSelected`)
- if cell is selected and /or has Focus too (`boolean hasFocus`)
- for row in the JTable (`int row`)
- in the Column from JTable (`int column`)

then there you can to change `Font`, `Border`, `Color`, `Icon` e.i.

NOTICE ---> don't change `Object value` in the `XxxRenderer`, never ever, be sure to try to avoid that

EDIT

- JTable has two dimmension there are defined only rows, have look at prepareRenderer
- prepareRenderer is designated for row coloring, [my question can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7132400/714968) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281306/714968), don't forget to override `int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);`, in most cases you can lost index model v.s. view, because JTable can be sorted or filtered

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is the following. It uses the table's fg and bg for painting the cell.

```
else {
    setBackground(table.getBackground());
    setForeground(table.getForeground());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `else` block to

```
 else if (cellComponent.getBackground != color){
         cellComponent.setBackground(white);
  }
```

Comment: I changed to:`else if (cellComponent.getBackground() != getColor()) { cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE); }` But the whole table get's the special color now (all cells).